# In new Firebase, how to use multiple config file in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Hey I am playing with the new firebase iOS SDK, in my project, I have only one target, I created two configurations, Debug and Release, with different bundler identifier， but seems like the config file downloaded from firebase only support one bundle identifier.

So anyone know how to use firebase within a multiple bundle identifier xcode project?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have different targets for the schemes, or are they both in the same target?

Comment: @IanBarber no I have only one target, I created two configurations, Debug and Release,  with different bundler identifier.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Update: see Firebase official documentation**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

**Updated with an easier solution:**

1. keep the same names for both GoogleService-Info.plist
2. put one GoogleService-Info.plist inside a subfolder, say "staging"
3. add references to both files in Xcode while linking them to corresponding targets
4. just use FIRApp.configure() in your AppDelegate, done

---

**My first attempt that didn't solve the issue:**

I renamed the second GoogleService-Info.json to something else and used following code to configure Firebase from AppDelegate.

```
// Swift code
#if STAGING
    let firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Staging-Info"
#else
    let firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info"
#endif
let firbaseOptions = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist"))
FIRApp.configureWithOptions(firbaseOptions)
```

If I run the Staging target, I will receive Firebase's complaint about 'Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.'. But then it says '<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3300000 started'.

As I checked on the Firebase dashboard, both production and staging apps have incoming user events being logged.

The above-mentioned configureWithOptions method is not documented in Firebase documentation, I figured it out by checking its source code. I'm not sure about what could be the downside of calling this. I would love to hear other approaches.

Comment: Your updated answer works if you have different targets. The original answer didn't worked for me. The Firebase config still tries to open the GoogleService-Info file. Thanks!

Comment: FIRApp.configureWithOptions is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_app#a2e4b970bfb6ed8b606c456f42a82b967

Comment: Your original answer does now work with the latest version of Firebase. configureWithOptions documentation is here, if anyone is interested: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIROptions#/c:objc(cs)FIROptions(im)initWithContentsOfFile:

Comment: Firebase includes [Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application) for how to do this now. Very close to what you have. Thank you!

Comment: Firebase official documentation is wrong for a one target app, their method will not work if you rename both files

Comment: The official docs url has a broken link, the new correct address is: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: `#if STAGING` how this works?? What flag u have set for this in Build Settings??

Comment: "Updated with an easier solution" is working for me. For multiple targets it helps. Thanks @chris chen

Answer (score 17):

I've implemented something similar, as I've had two schemes for a single target that have different bundle identifiers. In my examples below, I have two different schemes, one for UAT and one for PROD.

Create the two GoogleService-Info.json files, and put them into your project directory (not Xcode project) in different folders, e.g.

```
ROOT/config/UAT/GoogleService-Info.json
ROOT/config/PROD/GoogleService-Info.json
```

Then add the files to your Xcode project like so:

[image: Xcode project advised folder structure]

Now you need to add a Run Script in your Build Phases. This will need to be added before the Compile Sources stage:

[image: Drag the Run Script to above Compile Sources]

This Run Script takes the appropriately located json file and duplicates it into the build app directory, meaning Firebase/Google will identify it identically to how it would identify the file in a single identifier setup.

```
isUAT=`expr "$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" : ".*UAT=\([0-9]*\)"`

RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/config/PROD

if [ $isUAT = 1 ]; then
    RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/config/UAT
fi

BUILD_APP_DIR=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app

echo "Copying all files under ${RESOURCE_PATH} to ${BUILD_APP_DIR}"
cp -v "${RESOURCE_PATH}/"* "${BUILD_APP_DIR}/"
```

I would estimate you can use this same logic for Google Analytics as well, which uses a similar json config file setup.

Answer (score 14):

Better approach if you have single target is to just name your configs appropriately and load them as below. Seems to work fine for UAT environment
example : Swift 3.0

```
    var fireBaseConfigFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-PROD", ofType: "plist")
   #if UAT
       fireBaseConfigFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-UAT", ofType: "plist")
   #endif

   guard let firOptions = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: fireBaseConfigFile) else {
       assert(false, "Failed to load Firebase config file")
       return
   }

   FIRApp.configure(with: firOptions)
```

Comment: This was the easiest method I found and worked perfectly the first time. I wrote a quick gist on the method: https://gist.github.com/cohenadair/3a2aff5084603bfa65824f09cf74206e

Comment: Thank you @TheiOSChap , You made my day

Comment: You should never do that kind of things at runtime as it can impact your production analytics

Comment: The problematic thing about this solution is the need to include both files in your app bundle.

Comment: I recommend to use this approach, but leave the prod file named as "GoogleService-Info.plist" so that it matches the default and doesn't affect prod analytics.

Comment: I did the same but firebase console says, dSYM file missing.

Answer (score 12):

I did store 2 GoogleService-Info with different names:

- `GoogleService-Info.plist` for production
- `GoogleService-Info-Debug.plist` for development

And then go to `Build Phases`, add new run script:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/PathToYourGoogleServiceInfoFile/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Production plist copied"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/PathToYourGoogleServiceInfoFile/GoogleService-Info-Debug.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Development plist copied"
fi
```

Answer (score 11):

Add both Google Service plists to your project, with different names:

[image]

Then for each Build Scheme, select Edit Scheme and add a unique value for an environment variable like so:

[image]

So the other build scheme's BUILD_FOR environment variable would be set to "DEV", for example.

Then, you would check for this variable in App Delegate and configure the FIRApp according to which scheme was built:

```
    let buildFor = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["BUILD_FOR"]! as String
    var firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info"

    if buildFor == "PROD" {
        firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Prod-Info"
    }

    let firbaseOptions = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist"))
    FIRApp.configure(with: firbaseOptions!)
```

Comment: I haven't verified this, but if this is now possible with Firebase I would recommend this.

Comment: Just a note - do this in for example, the didFinishLauchingWithOptions function but do NOT do this in an override init method unless you want to break swizzling

Answer (score 9):

Using Objective-C, in your AppDeletage.m:

```
NSString *filePath;
#ifdef DEBUG
  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-Debug" ofType:@"plist"];
#else
  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-Production" ofType:@"plist"];
#endif

  FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In case I have more Scheme, I just add more flag and check like you.

Comment: Have my upvote for posting an ObjC example <3

Answer (score 6):

I see a lot of responses using Targets, but if you want to differentiate by scheme you can go to:

Edit Schemes... > Select Scheme > Build > Post-Action

- Add a Run Script
- Provide build settings from: (select the target you want to)
- Add following script

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/MVCVMRC/Supporting Files/FirebasePlist"

cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/Brazil/GoogleService-Info-preprod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

Don't forget to change the `PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS`

Sample:
[image: Sample]

Comment: this my preferred approach. I like it

Answer (score 2):

Firebase includes [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application) for how to do this now. I used this method in my app and it works great.

More specifically, I defined a custom Swift flag "BUILD_TYPE" in XCode and for each scheme, I define a unique value for that flag. Then, in my AppDelegate, I tell Firebase what `GoogleService-___.plist` file to load at runtime by this Swift flag value:

```
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-" + Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["BUILD_FLAVOR"] as! String, ofType: "plist")
    guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't load config file")
    }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest syntax is here to configure firebase for 2 targets (2 Plist files)

```
func configureFirebase() {
        let firebasePlistFileName = ConfigurationManager.sharedManager().firebasePlistName()
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist") {
            if let firbaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: path) {
                FirebaseApp.configure(options: firbaseOptions)
            }
        }
    }
```

**firebasePlistFileName** variable is just fetching the PList name based on current configuration i.e. Development or Production.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5, if you have different environnements, just do:

```
    guard let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: MYConstants.myFileName, ofType: "plist") ?? "") else {
        fatalError(false, "Failed to load Firebase config file")
    }
    
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```