# Two iOS apps under same Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I was able to configure two Android apps (dev and release) to be under the same Firebase project. Their data appear filtered by app, so I can see what comes from dev version, and what cames from release version.

But I couldn't achieve the same with iOS. I configured two apps, with different bundle IDs, but all the data goes to the first app to be configured, the dev app. When I test the builds using Debug View, they appear to be ok: the data from dev app goes to dev panel, and the data from release app goes to release panel. But all data from app in App Store goes to dev panel.

Note 1: the dev app was released only in TestFlight and Crashlytics Beta, not at the App Store. The release app was released in TestFlight and App Store.

Note 2: when I compare the GoogleServices.plist files, these are the differences:

- client id
- reversed client id
- bundle id
- google app id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In new Firebase, how to use multiple config file in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472090/in-new-firebase-how-to-use-multiple-config-file-in-xcode)

Comment: FYI, the Firebase team advises using multiple projects - one for each environment - rather than putting them all in the same project.

Comment: how do you set up the Google Services plist files?

Comment: @adbitx, I set up the Google Services plist files using different targets. The dev plist belogs to dev target, and production plist belongs to production target.

Comment: @keyvanvafaee: your edits to this question were _completely_ wrong (unnecessary bold, incorrect case adjustments, inappropriate quote devices, wrongly nested quotes). If you are looking just to get edit points, please stop now! Edits are meant to be helpful, not destructive.

Comment: @AndreiThomaz: I meant did you include both GoogleServices.plist files into the same app? Be careful that there should be only 1 GoogleServices plist file in an app. It is not guaranteed to use one of the files as you intended.

Comment: Dear all, I excluded all other plist files from master branch, and left dev plist on another branch, so now it is impossible to generate an .ipa with the wrong plist. The final binary is generated by another team, so we preferred this way. And it is working fine now. Thank you for all input.